# Authenticate windows 7 PCs with Radius server

Tags: windows, ubuntu, radius, freeradius

I have a network of Windows 7 PCs. And I am looking for a way to authenticate these computers through a centralized credential server. AD was one of the options but I don't have license for Windows server so I was trying to use Radius.

I installed freeradius on Ubuntu 22.04 and created users in the file /etc/freeradius/users.

But when it came to authenticating the Windows PCs against the Radius server, I couldn't find anything concrete. I know pGina can be configured to be used with radius but can we do it without downloading any external software?

Could anyone please advise?

Comment: Not sure if freeradius is possible but using Samba this should be possible: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_an_Active_Directory_Domain_Controller

Comment: Can it authenticate a user who is trying to login into the PC through windows login screen?

Comment: @Robert Kindly reply

Comment: As far as I know Samba can host a domain with authentication support for the Windows computers and users.

Comment: @Robert So, Samba can act as AD DC. But if I need to authenticate switches, routers which natively supports radius authentication, can I use freeradius for those cases to authenticate against samba DC?